# Error message trying to catch a soapfault using the PHP Soap class

Tags: php, soap

For some reason I can't catch the error. I'm following an example in O'Reillys PHP cookbook, so I'm not doing any cowboy coding (yet).

The error is:

```
SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Server] SoapFault::SoapFault() [soapfault.soapfault]: Invalid parameters. Invalid fault code. in C:\xampp\htdocs\soap\client_database.php:13 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\soap\client_database.php(13): SoapClient->__soapCall('select_query', Array) #1 {main}
```

Comment: That looks like a pretty normal exception. Do you have a try/catch block around the exception?

Comment: Yes. I have this after the try:
} catch (SOAPFault $exception) {
 print $exception;
}

Comment: I return a fault code and an error message, but it tells me the fault code is invalid, and doesn't print out my error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, you can only use certain error codes when throwing an error.

http://www.w3.org/TR/soap12-part1/#faultcodes

Answer (score 1):

As per [the standards](http://www.w3.org/TR/soap12-part1/#faultcodes) there are only 5 possible options for a fault code:

1. VersionMismatch
2. MustUnderstand
3. DataEncodingUnknown
4. Sender
5. Receiver

Choose the most appropriate to your situation and use that one as a value for $faultCode when throwing a SoapFault exception.

Answer (score 0):

I got other (weird) SOAP errors in php 5.2.0 which where resolved in php 5.2.8

If you're not on the latest version of php I suggest upgrading and see what happens

Comment: I'm on 5.2.4 I think. May upgrade later. The SOAP library is quite new I think, still a few teething problems.